# Different behaviour of asyncio.Task.all_tasks()

Tags: python-asyncio

First example:

```
import asyncio

async def req():
    print('request')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def run():
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    asyncio.ensure_future(req())
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

The result is:

```
1
2
request
1
```

Second example:

```
import asyncio

async def req():
    print('request')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def run():
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    t = asyncio.ensure_future(req())
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
    await t
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

The result is:

```
1
2
request
2
```

So, why in first example the last call **asyncio.Task.all_tasks()** return 1 and in second example it's return 2?
In other words, why in first example the task, that wrap req() was deleted from a set of all tasks for an event loop, and why it is not true for the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is removed from `all_tasks()` when it is [destroyed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L36).

Add a `del` statement:

```
    [...]
    await t
    del t
    print(len(asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
```

and it will yield:

```
1
2
request
1
```

Comment: therefore,asyncio.Task.all_tasks will return finished tasks until I will clear all variables, that referencing on it in my program

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7174. asyncio.all_tasks() now only returns pending tasks.