# Python 3.6 asyncio - Task exception was never retrieved - Task got bad yield: 200

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, python-asyncio

I've read the other questions and answers, and still am not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to create an Elasticsearch 6.x producer in Python 3.6 using ES' asyncio implementation (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py-async) and while it works (the records are successfully pushed into ES), I get `Task Exception was never retried` and `Task got bad yield: 200` errors.  I assume they're both resulting from the same issue and one probably causes the other?

I'm using the following modules:

```
python 3.6
elasticsearch=6.3.1
elasticsearch-async=6.2.0
boto3=1.9.118
```

Below is my code:

```
import json
import boto3
import logging
import os
import gzip
import asyncio
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection
from elasticsearch_async import AsyncElasticsearch
from assume_role_aws4auth import AssumeRoleAWS4Auth
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Operating constants
MAX_RECORDS_IN_BATCH = 500
MAX_BATCH_SIZE = 10000000

# boto3 clients
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AssumeRoleAWS4Auth(credentials, 'us-east-1', 'es')

cloudwatch_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

es_client = AsyncElasticsearch(hosts=['https://ES_HOST'], http_compress=True, http_auth=awsauth, use_ssl=True,
                               verify_certs=True, connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, loop=event_loop)


def lambda_handler(filename, context):
    event_loop.run_until_complete(process(filename))
    pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending))


async def process(filename: str):
    for action_chunk in read_chunk(filename, MAX_BATCH_SIZE, MAX_RECORDS_IN_BATCH):
        try:
            resp = asyncio.ensure_future(es_client.bulk(body=action_chunk, index='index', doc_type='type', _source=False))
            await asyncio.sleep(.1)
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(ex)


def read_chunk(file_path: str, max_batch_size: int, max_records: int):
    actions: str = ''
    actions_size: int = 0
    num_actions: int = 0
    with gzip.open(file_path, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            request = json.dumps(dict({'index': dict({})})) + '\n' + line + '\n'
            request_size = len(request.encode('utf-8'))

            # Check to see if this record will put us over the limits
            if (actions_size + request_size) > max_batch_size or num_actions == max_records:
                yield actions
                actions = ''
                num_actions = 0
                actions_size = 0

            # Add the record
            actions += request
            num_actions += 1
            actions_size += request_size

    if actions != '':
        yield actions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler('/path/to/file', None)
```

Below is the error I get each time I call `es_client.bulk`:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<AsyncTransport.main_loop() done, defined at /path/to/PythonElasticsearchIngest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_async/transport.py:143> exception=RuntimeError('Task got bad yield: 200',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/PythonElasticsearchIngest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_async/transport.py", line 150, in main_loop
    method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  Also, if there is anything I can be doing better / more efficient, I'd love to hear it.  I wanted to use the Helpers package, but there is no asyncio implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the problem but here's what may happen.

You create multiple tasks inside `process()` coroutine, but don't store references to them. It may lead to a problem: some tasks are [garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46284630/1113207) before you could explicitly retrieve their results. If such thing happens `asyncio` [warns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-never-retrieved-exceptions) you about situation.

To solve it you should store all created tasks and ensure all of them are awaited:

```
tasks = []

# ...

async def process(filename: str):
    # ...
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(...)
    tasks.append(task)
    # ...


def lambda_handler(filename, context):
    # ...
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks ))
```

If my guess is correct you'll probably see `RuntimeError('Task got bad yield: 200',)` raised at `lambda_handler`. You can retrieve all exceptions without raising them passing `return_exceptions=True` param to [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). This way you avoid warnings (but not underlying reason why those exceptions happened it tasks in the first place).

Sorry, can't help further than here.

**Upd:**

I altered answer fixing mistake of original version.

Comment: I wonder if it's necessary to add `task.result()` after the `run_until_complete(gather(...))`. Shouldn't `gather` and `run_until_complete` have already accessed the task results in order to return them?

Comment: So is the “bad yield” the underlying error that I should be able to get a backtrack on?

Comment: @user4815162342 you're absolutely right, I confused `gather` behavior with `wait` behavior. Thanks for correcting me! I altered answer with the other presumption.

Comment: @Brooks exactly. It probably happens somewhere inside `es_client.bulk`. Take a note, my version about reason of warning was wrong, I altered it to (I hope) correct one.

Comment: Good idea, the GC getting to the task before the code could well be the issue. I'm still wondering about the second call to `run_until_complete` in the @Brooks 's code code - is it necessary and what is it supposed to accomplish, because it looks dangerous, given that it's hard to tell what tasks will be returned. @Brooks, can you comment on that part?

Comment: I can't.  Tbh, I'm really pretty new to Python, just getting my feet wet and I've yet to get a firm handle on how the asyncio module works.  If I am doing something wrong, I am happy to fix it.  I'll try the suggestion above and modify my question.

Comment: Can you clarify how I should call the process(...) method in your suggestion?